# ng-minlength of 2 not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularjs snippet containing a minlength check. The min length is 2. When I enter numbers like 2, 3, 4,5 to 9 it complains of ng-length. But when enter 10 or 11 it does not complain of ng-length. Here is the input with the ng-length check

```
<label>Items</label>
              <input ng-minlength="2" ng-model="items" name="dInto" 
               type="number" class="ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched">

              <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.dInto.$error.type">Please enter a number</span>
              <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.dInto.$error.minlength">Must be 2 or more</span>
```

Please why am having this experience of ng-length beginning from 10 whereas I coded 2

Comment: This is because the length of 10 is 2. after 10 it will work. But when the number is less than 10 it will show error. What exactly you want to do?

Comment: What is your expected result ?

Comment: @KaustubhKhare I want if I enter digit 1 then it should inform me that minlenth must be 2

Comment: @rocket It is working fine. Check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/spB0R3krvrUADNxQheUP?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code.

```
   <label>Items</label>
              <input ng-model="items" name="dInto" 
               type="number" class="ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched">

              <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.dInto.$error.type">Please enter a number</span>
              <span style="color:red" ng-show="items < 3">Must be 2 or more</span>
```

Comment: please what is this doing <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>

Comment: I implemented your code, it works fine but it does not disable the validation button even upon entering 1 and the error is showing

Comment: the essence of using this at first <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.dInto.$error.type">Please enter a number</span> was to disable the submit button

Comment: Ok. You want to disable button as well

Comment: bro first give the full requirement and then we will provide the sufficient code

Answer (score 1):

Because `ng-minlength` is for restricting minimum characters,in your case it should be two digit minimum.

The ng-minlength directive adds a restriction to an input field, and to the validator of the form.

The ng-minlength directive will add an "invalid" state of the input field if the length of the value is less than specified.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <body ng-app="">

        <form name="myForm">

        <p>An error will be displayed when you type anything less than 2 characters in the input field:</p>

        <input name="myInput" type="number" ng-model="myInput"  required>
    <span style="color:red" ng-show="myInput < 2">Must be 2 or more</span>

        </form>


        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: I dont want to be valid when it is empty

Comment: Your answer is not allowing me to enter 3, it shows the error message

Comment: then you can add `required` as i mentioned to input so you it wont be valid when it is empty

Comment: Yeah, I want to check for the value and ensure that it takes from digit 2 upwards

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176554/discussion-between-sa-e-chowdary-and-rocket).

Comment: I think you don understand, I want to check to ensure that it takes just letter 2 upwards

Comment: @SaEChowdary I think he wants to compare value from 2 and upwards. He confuse with concept of `minlength`.

Comment: just now i got it @KaustubhKhare

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">
 
 <form name="myForm">
    <label>Items</label>
              <input ng-model="items" name="dInto" type="number" class="ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched">

              <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.dInto.$error.type">Please enter a number</span>
              <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.dInto.$error.minlength">Must be 2 or more</span>
              </form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I think you are looking for this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 
 <form name="myForm">
    <label>Items</label>
    <input ng-model="items" name="dInto" 
               type="number" ng-keyup="validate(items)" class="ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched">

    <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.dInto.$error.type">Please enter a number</span>
    <span style="color:red" ng-show="isValid">Must be 2 or more</span>
 </form>

</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.isValid = false;
    
    $scope.validate = function(value){
      if(value && value<=1){
         $scope.isValid = true;
      }else{
         $scope.isValid = false;
      }
    }
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you don understand, I want to check to ensure that it takes just letter 2 upwards

Comment: 2 Upwards means 2 or 10?

Comment: your answer does not disable a button